# How can I stop App Engine images.get_serving_url returning a scaled down image?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have just started using google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url to serve images uploaded to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). Following the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images) I am just calling

```
url = google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url(blob_key, secure_url=True)
```

This does successfully return a serving url. However the image size is considerably lower than what's hosted in GCS. I have attempted to add the "=s1600" flags to the url (or any other integer, even 32) but that returns a 404.

Is there any way to serve the original size image, rather than a scaled down version or is this an app engine bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `=s0` to the end of the URL will return the original size.